# ATI Radeon 5770 Eyefinity - three monitors

Tags: amd-radeon

How do I setup [Eyefinity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_%28GPU_family%29) to support three monitors on a Radeon [HD 5770](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evergreen_%28GPU_family%29#Radeon_HD_5700) card? Currently I can setup only two at once in any combination.

Monitors are connected as DVI-DVI-HDMI.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

On *[AMD Eyefinity Technology](http://www.amd.com/us/products/technologies/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity.aspx)*, there is this remark at the bottom:

> Driver version 8.66 (Catalyst 9.10) or above is required to support ATI Eyefinity technology and ***to enable a third display you require one panel with a DisplayPort connector.***

Do you have one screen connected with [DisplayPort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort)?

Comment: Arrgh. Thats the catch! Well I do not have DisplayPort monitor. But I am going to the local shop for DisplayPort to HDMI adapter.

Comment: I have still problems: now I have DVI-DVI-DP and still drivers do not allow to have three monitors. What to do?

Comment: Hehe you forgot about getting a new DP display. =) Dell UltraSharp series are quite ok.

Comment: @Peter First make sure that it's an **active** DP->HDMI adapter. If it is, then you may need to use both display ports instead of only one. [This page](http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx) has more info on Eyefinity connectivity.

Answer (score 9):

This cannot be solved with a passive adapter. Issue is in hardware and comes down to signaling on DVI, HDMI and DisplayPort.

If I recall correctly DVI and HDMI require an own clock signal per output. Because DisplayPort is a package protocol it requires only one clock signal per card. ATI Radeon HD 5000-series has two clocks for DVI/HDMI so it is possible only to use 2 of those devices, adapters do not change this fact.

There is however an active adater, that allows you to transform DisplayPort signal to DVI-signal. More information about the device [here](http://www.techpowerup.com/110927/SAPPHIRE_Solves_Eyefinity_Issue_with_Active_DisplayPort_Adapter.html)

So what you need is a native DisplayPort monitor or an active device that transforms DisplayPort signal to DVI/HDMI.

Comment: Your explanation is correct, but the initial comment is not. It *can* be solved with an adapter, but you need an active adapter that will use the clock signal from the DisplayPort.

Comment: I should have used word passive in first paragraph (now added). Active adapter is however mentioned in third paragraph.

Comment: I'd add to this that if you want to get the third monitor working on the cheap you CAN use a Displayport-VGA passive adapter, and it'll work fine (as I've just found out). I'm assuming from Ahe's answer that trying to do a DVIx3 from a HD 5770 card will require an active adapter.

Comment: I've used a passive adapter on my ATI card and it worked fine with 3 displays, so perhaps they've made some updates to make this possible?