# Eyefinity on HD 5700/5800 Series - 3 monitors setup

Tags: amd-radeon, eyefinity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ATI Radeon 5770 Eyefinity - 3 monitors](https://superuser.com/questions/66665/ati-radeon-5770-eyefinity-3-monitors)

How to setup Eyefinity to support three monitors on HD 5700/5800 series card?

Monitors are connected the following way: **DVI-DVI-DisplayPort**

Currently driver does not allow me to do this. If I click on the third monitor to extended it, I get message to disable other one.

Message:

[image]

I am using DisplayPort adapter to DVI, so I do not have native displayPort monitor. Might be that a problem?

Comment: What kind of adapter do you have? Apparently you need an active one, as explained here: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/page-272593_15_0.html

Comment: Verly likely passive I have this adapter: http://www.manhattan-products.com/en-US/products/8102-displayport-adapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To establish Eyefinity on three monitors you can only do this to use DisplayPort connection. You can connect on DisplayPort only a native DisplayPort monitor or DVI/HDMI/VGA monitor with **ACTIVE** DisplayPort adapter.

Picture of active adapter.

[image]

All credits should go to the [Snark](https://superuser.com/users/10131/snark), since he gave the crucial hint.

Comment: Are anyone knows where to order this adapter (to Europe)?

Comment: ATI Response: 
Currently you must have a Display Port monitor with no adapters.  Passive adapters do not work.  Active adapters are being tested and some are working, once testing is complete a list of Active adapters should be available online.

Comment: Here's the list of approved dongles: http://support.amd.com/us/eyefinity/Pages/eyefinity-dongles.aspx