# Why cant I get 3 monitors working with my ati 5770

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, vga, amd-radeon

I have an ati 5770, card with vga, dvi and hdmi output.  I can only get 2 out of the 3 monitors working at once, however i can change the configuation so that all monitors can be selected, but only 2 will work at once..  2 of my monitors have dvi inputs and one has vga.
in my catyalist control center it shows all 3 monitors are there but either 2 can be selected at a time, and so the same with my windows 7. I have and adapter which i use on the 3rd monitor, hdmi-dvi adaptor and it works.  also when i boot up my pc i get 2 monitors booting up and when windows starts the 3rd monitor boots but the 1st one closes. I looked at my package box and it actualy does specify ati eyefinity technology is available with this card.

why wont it work???

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/66665/ati-radeon-5770-eyefinity-3-monitors

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of [this ATI support page](http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/gpu50-ati-eyefinity-display-configs.aspx) it states that for more than two monitors, the additions displays need DisplayPort connectors.

Comment: ok, back.. ive worked it out i need this device..Accell UltraAV B087B-002B DisplayPort/DVI-D Dual-Link Adapter (Black)

Comment: @G-Dogg - No, that adapter is going the wrong way. You need a DVI to DisplayPort, or an HDMI to DisplayPort. That device is a DisplayPort to DVI, which won't get you anywhere. Also, your third monitor needs DisplayPort as an input type, which you did not list meaning you will have to get another adapter which will kill the quality, or get a new monitor.

Comment: thanx MarkM, if you know of any can u provide a link.. thanx

Comment: back again and reading some more reivews the dp needs to be active..

ttp://www.techpowerup.com/110927/SAPPHIRE_Solves_Eyefinity_Issue_with_Active_DisplayPort_Adapter.html

Comment: REQUIRED:  DISPLAYPORT AT BOTH ENDS, (GPU end AND monitor end). Conversion does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought an ATI 5770 card and was disappointed to discover that the DisplayPort adapter had to be active for EyeFinity to drive a third monitor.

It's a good solution if you can only install a single graphics card, but at ~$100 for an active adapter, I think I'll just use another 5750/5770 card. They can also be used in CrossFire as a bonus.

Comment: Also note, DISPLAYPORT AT BOTH ENDS.  You _cannot_ use a DisplayPort-DVI adapter and make it work, I just tried.