# My Ati Radeon HD 5450 PCIexpress card with DisplayPort will not let me use 3 monitors, why?

Tags: graphics-card, display, multiple-monitors, amd-radeon

My Ati Radeon HD 5450 PCIexpress card with DisplayPort will not let me use 3 monitors, why?  I have a new computer running Win7 and the Ati Radeon HD 5450 PCIexpress card with DisplayPort.  It shows all three monitors but, when trying to enable the third, I am told that I have to disable one of the others first.  All ports work but only Two at a time.  Why?!!  I am using CCC 10.7 along with the most recent driver.

Also, it says it uses EyeFinity and I cannot find that anywhere.  Is it integrated in the driver?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I think EyeFinity requires all monitors to have the same resolution.  Is this the case with your setup?

Comment: You may find the following entry from 2009 has already answered your question. Have a look through http://superuser.com/questions/66665/ati-radeon-5770-eyefinity-3-monitors and see if it applies to your situation :)

Answer (score 1):

The ports on the back of the 5000 series cards might have more then a total of 2 DVI and HDMI ports but the hardware to output to those ports is only there for 2. To get the 3rd display outputting as well, you need to use the Display Port connection.

You can have 1 DVI + 1 HDMI + 1 DP or you can have 2 DVI + 1 DP or 2 HDMI + 1 DP to get the triple screen setup on one card.

Answer (score 1):

[Converting DisplayPort and/or HDMI to DVI-D?](https://superuser.com/questions/118957/converting-displayport-and-or-hdmi-to-dvi-d) links to http://www.anandtech.com/show/2841/2 which says:

> The only catch to this specific port
>   layout is that the card still only has
>   enough TMDS transmitters for two
>   ports. So you can use 2x DVI or 1x DVI
>   + HDMI, but not 2x DVI + HDMI. For 3 DVI-derived ports, you will need an
>   active DisplayPort-to-DVI adapter.