# Can I run the video output on my motherboard along side a separate video card?

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-radeon, displayport

I recently built a new computer using a [ASUS M4A785TD-V](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813131398) motherboard. So far I've only been using the on-board video, but recently just orderd a [HIS H577FK1GD Radeon HD 5770](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814161338). After reading about the Eyefinity stuff it sounded like I'd be able to run more then two monitors with this card. However, later I found [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/66665/ati-radeon-5770-eyefinity-3-monitors) which says that the third display must have a Display Port input, which I don't have. Nor do I want to spend $100 on an active adapter.

I have two 19" monitors with VGA and DVI inputs, as well as a 32" TV with HDMI and VGA inputs that I want to run. I'd prefer to not use any VGA if possible. When I get the new card will it be possible to hook the two 19" monitors up the DVI outputs on the new HD5770, and plug the 32" Tv into the exsisting HDMI on my motherboard?

I remember with the old IGPs on AGP motherboards if you were to plug in a AGP card it would disable the onboard video. Is this still the case with these new motherboards?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is it depends. Some motherboard will disable your on-board video automatically. If it does then there little chance you will be able to hook 3 monitors between your on-board video and PCI-E video card.

<strike>Have never work with your motherboard before I can't say if your will auto disable the on-board once a video card is installed.</strike> After reading a little I found more information. On the bright side, looks like the ASUS M4A785TD-V motherboard will not disable the on-board video. However, a future update will change. The bad news is, there are a few people experience problem when the on-board video is enable with an graphic card plugged in too. Read the user's comments at this [post](http://www.anandtech.com/show/3559).