# 3 Monitors Connected, 2 Working Only

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, dvi, displayport

I have an AMD R9 200 Series graphic cards which has 2 DVI, 1 HDMI, and 1 DisplayPort ports available. I've connected two monitors which DVI and the other with HDMI but only 2 work. I've read from this post which is almost a [duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/249667/three-monitors-hooked-up-but-i-can-only-use-two) but my take on the answer is that the OP of that question's card doesn't not have 3 monitor capability at all. Whereas with my card, it should since it has a DisplayPort option. Now do I have to buy a DVI to Displayport adapter or is there a way to "tweak" to make it work as is?

Comment: What is the make/model of your GPU? What driver version is installed?

Comment: @Ash I have this model: http://www.gigabyte.us/products/product-page.aspx?pid=4795#ov and driver version is: 15.12 Crimson Edition.

Comment: Are both monitors connected to DVI-(D/I) the same? According to http://www.gigabyte.us/support-downloads/faq-page.aspx?fid=3327&pid=4795, they need to be the same.

Comment: When it says the same, does it mean the same model? If so then no, each monitor is different model/brands..

Comment: If thats the case then would a DVI to DisplayPort suffice?